# want to specify each row of tableView from data from Appcelerator cloud

Tags: javascript, android, titanium, tableview, appcelerator

Im developing an android app with PC with titanium/appcelerator cloud service.

I want to have the facebook's newsfeed page where list of user's post comes down.

I have managed to do this with tableView with each row displaying each post from the server.

The problem is that I somehow can not get the individual user;s photo AND (that there is button for each posts) if i clikc this button, it doesnt give me the user information of that specific user but the user of the first post.

for example, if user1, user2, user3 posts one each, 
the list page shows post1, post2, post3 respectively.
If i click the button of post2(which is send message button), it tries to send it to user1 not user2.

here is my code.

been stuck for last 2 days,,
THANKS!

profileimage  is the variable for photo 
shopping is the variable for the message send button

```
win.addEventListener('open', function () {
Cloud.Posts.query({
    page: 1,
    per_page: 20,
    order: "-created_at"
}, function (e) {
    if (e.success) {
        status.hide();

      var tbl_data = [];   
        for (var i = 0; i < e.posts.length; i++) {
            var post = e.posts[i];

        -- there are some code here ---

            var profileimage = Ti.UI.createView({
                backgroundImage: post.user.photo.urls.medium_500,
                backgroundColor: '#fffff',
                width: 90,
                height: 90,
                borderRadius: 22,
                top:20, left: 10
            });

            var shopping = Ti.UI.createView({
                backgroundImage: 'shopping.png',
                width: 35,
                height: 35,
                top: 70,
                right: 10
            });

            shopping.addEventListener('click', function(){
                //alert(post);
                var tradewin,tradeinc;
                    tradeinc = require('trade');
                    tradewin = new tradeinc.trade1(post);
                    tradewin.open();
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems as though your issue stems from adding the click event listeners for all of the `shopping` views inside the `for` loop. When the `shopping` click function is actually called due to user action it accesses the **most recent value** of `post` which will always be the value of `post` at the end of the `for` loop: `e.posts[e.post.length - 1]`. I've modified your code to alleviate this issue:

```js
win.addEventListener('open', function () {
    Cloud.Posts.query({
        page: 1,
        per_page: 20,
        order: "-created_at"
    }, function (e) {
        if (e.success) {
            status.hide();

            var tbl_data = [];   
            for (var i = 0; i < e.posts.length; i++) {
                var post = e.posts[i];

            -- there are some code here ---

                var profileimage = Ti.UI.createView({
                    backgroundImage: post.user.photo.urls.medium_500,
                    backgroundColor: '#fffff',
                    width: 90,
                    height: 90,
                    borderRadius: 22,
                    top:20, left: 10
                });

                var shopping = Ti.UI.createView({
                    backgroundImage: 'shopping.png',
                    width: 35,
                    height: 35,
                    top: 70,
                    right: 10
                });

                // This wrapper function returns a callback function
                // for your click event that also maintains the correct
                // value of `post`
                function getShoppingClickCallback(associatedPost) {
                    return function () {
                        var tradewin, tradeinc;

                        tradeinc = require('trade');
                        tradewin = new tradeinc.trade1(associatedPost);
                        tradewin.open();
                    };
                }

                // This line calls the `getShoppingClickCallback` function and
                // passes the associated `post` object. The returned value of
                // `getShoppingClickCallback` is a callback function.
                shopping.addEventListener('click', getShoppingClickCallback(post));
```

Using a helper function like `getShoppingClickCallback` when adding event listeners in a `for` loop is a really helpful pattern. I suggest trying this out in your project and seeing if your issue persists. I hope it doesn't! :)

Comment: You're welcome! If you wouldn't mind marking my answer as being correct it would be much appreciated!